# how to make join in laravel ? get only some columns of another table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, join, eloquent

I am working on admin panel ... where i get all products from database and show in table ... the problem is i want to get each product categorey from "category" table and get stock of each product from "products attribute" table ... i am create a join but this join collapse product id , name stock or prize from another table... Thanks.

```
  public function viewProducts(Request $request){
    $products = Product::get();

    $products = Product::join('categories','categories.id','products.category_id')
    ->join('products_attributes','products_attributes.product_id',
            'products.id')
    ->get();

    $products = json_decode(json_encode($products));

    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($products); die;

    return view('admin.products.view_products')->with(compact('products'));
}
```

Comment: Add a ->select() method to the query and tell it you also want items from the other joined tables. ->select('categories.*','products.*') or if you want everything, just ->select('*')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$products = Product::join('categories','categories.id','products.category_id')
->join('products_attributes','products_attributes.product_id','products.id')
->get(['categories.category_name as category_name', 'products_attributes.stock as product_stock', 'products.*']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Product::join('categories','categories.id','products.category_id')
->join('products_attributes','products_attributes.product_id','products.id')
->select(['categories.category_name as category_name', 'products_attributes.stock as product_stock', 'products.*'])
->get()->toArray();
```